# Pulling data out of JSON Object via jq to CSV in Bash

Tags: json, export-to-csv, jq

I'm working on a bash script (running via gitBash on Windows technically but I don't think that matters) that will convert some JSON API data into CSV files.  Most of it has gone fairly well, especially since I'm not particularly familiar with JQ as this is my first time using it.

I've got some JSON data that looks like the array below.  What I'm trying to do is select the cardType,MaskedPan,amount and datetime out of the data.

this is probably the first time in life that my google searching has failed me.  I know(or should I say think) that that is actually an object and not just a simple array.

I've not really found anything that helps me know how to grab that data I need and export it into a CSV file.  I've had no issue grabbing the other data that I need but these few pieces are proving to be a big problem for me.

The script I'm trying basically can be boiled down to this:

```
jq='/c/jq-win64.exe -r';

header='("cardType")';

fields='[.TransactionDetails[0].Value[0].cardType]';

$jq ''$header',(.[] | '$fields' | @csv)' < /t/API_Data/JSON/GetByDate-082719.json > 
/t/API_Data/CSV/test.csv;
```

If I do .TransactionDetails[0].Value I can get that whole chunk of data.  But that is problematic in a CSV as it contains commas.

I suppose I could make this a TSV and import it into the database as one big string and sub string it out.  But that isn't the "right" solution.  I'm sure there is a way JQ can give me what I need.

```
    "TransactionDetails": [
        {
            "TransactionId": 123456789,
            "Name": "BlacklinePaymentDetail",
            "Value": "{\"cardType\":\"Visa\",\"maskedPan\":\"1234\",\"paymentDetails\":{\"reference\":\"123456789012\",\"amount\":99.99,\"dateTime\":\"2019/08/27 08:41:09\"}}",
            "ShowOnTill": false,
            "PrintOnOrder": false,
            "PrintOnReceipt": false
        }
    ]
```

Ideally I'd be able to just have a field in the CSV for cardType,MaskedPan,amount and datetime instead of pulling the "Value" that contains all of it.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ingredient you're missing is `fromjson`, which converts a stringified JSON to JSON.  Adding enclosing braces around your sample input,
the invocation:

```
jq -r -f program.jq input.json
```

produces:

```
"Visa","1234",99.99,"2019/08/27 08:41:09"
```

where program.jq is:

```
.TransactionDetails[0].Value
| fromjson
| [.cardType, .maskedPan] + (.paymentDetails | [.amount, .dateTime])
| @csv
```